# WebRTC between two endpoints in the same browser page?

Tags: websocket, webrtc

Is it technically possible to create a WebRTC connection for transferring JSON between two WebRTC endpoints spawned in the same script on the same page in the same browser?

For example, could I code an HTML5 offline app to communicate between different parts of the app over "local" WebRTC?

This is not a question about whether this is a good idea or whether I should be doing something a different way!  Just "is this technically possible?"

Comment: @jibrewery showed the "simplest webrtc example on two tab pages on the same browser without internet" in another stackoverflow question. But the stackoverflow moderator prevent me to paste a link to the anwer in that question.

Comment: the anwser link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35300241/264181

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible, because the implementation of web sockets in a browser are client implementations. For point-to-point communication you would need a web socket server instance, which you cannot create in a browser.
Maybe, you should have a look at WebRTC.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a very good sample in this web: https://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab

To be more exact, in the step 5:

"In the examples already completed, the 'sender' and 'receiver' RTCPeerConnection objects are on the same page, so signaling is simply a matter of passing objects between methods.

In a real world application, the sender and receiver RTCPeerConnections are not on the same page, and we need a way for them to communicate metadata."

You can run the samples to understand better how it works.